# Minimum Spanning Trees problem with multiple roots

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, trees, network-flow

I'm looking for algorithms that handle the minimum spanning tree problem on connected graph with multiple roots. In other words, the resultant trees are radial graphs.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please add some details to clarify your questions

Comment: In particular, it's not clear what you mean by a root of a graph, and it's not clear what you mean by a radial graph.